# Android Studio tries to download a version of gradle everytime i open a project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Every time i try to open an existing project that i downloaded, i get the syncing message and it 

keep trying to download another version of gradle

i want to open projects without wasting my time

so, how can i open a project that i have downloaded and just open it without focring me to download something and just waste my time?
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: with the same version 2.2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before opening your project go to **\ AndroidStudioProjects \ YourProject \ gradle \ wrapper**

Open `gradle-wrapper.properties` file with any Text Editor, change this line :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-x.x.x-all.zip
```

To

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-Y.Y.Y-all.zip
```

**Y.Y.Y** means the version of Gradle that you already downloaded it before, for example :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save your changes, now open your project normally

if the issue still present, make sure that the folder of Gradle is not being deleted by any software you installed in your pc.

to check for the downloaded Gradle folder go to :

**\ AndroidStudioProjects \ YourProject \ .gradle**